# Relieving formalities , suggestions for assigned tasks

Tags: resignation, software-development, tech-industry, relieving-letter

I have recently put my resignation (having a good offer from another organization).
I have a good reputation with employees and management of my current organization.

I have been an exceptional contributor, have won several awards and have a patent on my name too.

In recent years, I have worked on several ideas/innovations and successfully implemented those for my current organizations.

My reporting manager wants me to completely implement one of his idea (of which initially I was a part of and did most of the implementations) before I leave.

However, due to some personal preferences, I am planning to wrap up other tasks, since I did half of his idea implementation.

He said he would sign the reliving form only if he can see this all working. I am not sure how to handle this and I am afraid that even if I make it successful, he would still want me to add/implement more.

He says if it can be a patent/trade secret, we both will be owners.

I do not trust his words, at the same time I am afraid that he may create any havoc during my last date, and will not sign the reliving form.

Any suggestion on how to approach would be very helpful.

PS: This idea implementation is technical in nature (required programming skills and specific hardware knowledge) and it does not affect any of project deadlines/milestones

Comment: @AnneDaunted Yeah, but I am open to suggestions. I can still do want he wants me to do but is it okay for managers to ask such _"favors"_ before relieving. Am I liable for such requests, do I need to approach HR or my bosses' boss?

Comment: To protect your rights, you might want to consult a lawyer who specializes on intellectual property in your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put simply, he is blackmailing, which is unacceptable. You should get your relieving form signed by HR and they have no reason not to accept it other than asking for trouble.

If you need advice how to politely decline this "offer", simply say you are not interested in owning the patent nor in money and pursue other goals. You can negociate doing the tasks you would like to finish instead. Feel free to report to his boss as well if he insists on blackmailing and becomes difficult.

Note however, being under his responsibility, you still have to complete what he assigns you to do no matter what your personnal preference is.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, do not trust any words, 
look up for number one and do everything by the book.

Contract you signed should contain exit clause with number of days you have to give your advance notice and any other responsibilities you may have.

If you do all according to your contract exit clause, your manager can do nothing but get himself in trouble if he wouldn't sign, as HR is always available for you to approach.

On the other hand, if you want to loose the opportunity you have right now for a chance of having another patent under your name, DOCUMENT EVERYTHING and make sure the agreement is signed by all parties involved and can have legal standing.